# how transport DIV in another area?

Tags: html, area, transport

Please help me! I create a interesting page and wanna transport my div's (or ul>li objects) in  another field,  is located in a different location on the screen, if they do not have enough space.

[image]

and there is my code:

```
<div id="container1">
 <div id="block"></div>
 <div id="block"></div>
 <div id="block"></div>
    <div id="block"></div> 
    <div id="block"></div> 
 </div>

 <!-- other content -->

 <div id="container2">
    <!-- need #block4,5 there -->
 </div>
```

see JsFiddle: `http://jsfiddle.net/GAZS4/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use from jQuery.appendTo method
check this fiddle:

```
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/rasoolghafari/XJmbN/)
```